# I cannot adapt all the commit messages in Git repository migrated from SVN repository

Tags: git, svn, version-control, migration, git-svn

I am trying to migrate SVN repository to GIT repository. After migrating I have to adapt all the commit messages since they are linked to Jira issues. I used Tortoise Git using its GUI feature as well as the git commands to migrate the repository using the below commands. Migration steps:-

Initialize local Git repo:-
`git init`

Then migrate the SVN repo code to this local GIT repo, via the below steps:-

`git svn init http://<SVN URL>`
`git config svn.authorsfile ../authors.txt`
`git svn fetch`

Next step would have been to push the local GIT repo code to the remote Bitbucket repo, but I am stuck as I am unable to modify all the commit messages of the repo.
After the code has been migrated to the local repo, I am using rebase command to change the commit messages manually.
`git rebase -i HEAD~54`

Now the challenge is that the first line is commented as shown below as the snippet. (PS., I cannot share the actual data due to data sharing restrictions, but the below eg, is similar.)
**# pick qliuefgeoifgeifgefgoqfegufeouf JIRAISSUE-123 New Node ABCD..**
**pick qwertyu JIRAISSUE-101 Old Node is generating issue.**
**pick zxcvbnm JIRAISSUE-110 New Node added.**
...

As I needed to change all the commit messages in the repo, I cannot change the first commit message which is commented.
Please advise me on how this one can be resolved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22hash+sign%22+message

Comment: For example, `git -c core.commentChar='>' rebase -i HEAD~54`

Comment: Thanks @phd , the solution worked, can you please also help for one more issue, I am seeing that total no. of commits in the git repo is 55, but when I run ``` git rebase -i HEAD~55 ``` , I face error <invalid upstream HEAD~55>, hence I have to use the cmd, git rebase -i HEAD~54 as I cannot adapt the base commit msg , rest all commit msgs are adaptable. can you please help how to adapt the base commit message as well.

Comment: `git rebase -i --root master` or whatever branch you rebase.